# Counting and calculating over different tables in MS access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have three tables in my Microsoft access that stores the following data.

Wight table

```
tbl_weights
------------------------
Bill Number| Weight
1111          50
1112          60
1113          70
1114          30
```

The second table stores the pallets which were weighted:

```
tbl_pallets
------------------------
Pallet ID | Weighting Bill Number
ZM-001      1111
ZM-002      1111
ZM-003      1111
ZM-004      1112
ZM-005      1112
ZM-006      1113
```

The third table stores equipment data:

```
tbl_equipments
----------------------------
equipment ID | Pallets
O-001         ZM-001,ZM-002
O-002         ZM-003
O-003         ZM-003,ZM-004
```

The Pallets column is a multi-value field.

I need to calculate each equipment weight and store it on a table. How can I do that?

In a simple programming language, I would have a loop over each `pallet` in the `tbk_equipments` and search for the appearance of the corresponding pallet ID on the `tbl_pallets` then count the number of `Weighting Bill Number` and divide the corresponding weight for that bill number by the number of repetition of the bill number and then sum all of the resulted values to get the final answer. But I don't know how is the process in MS access.

I have tried "calculated fields" in the access but it does not allow me to have access to the fields on the other tables. I thought maybe there is a query or a function in VBA that I can use.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What does "I need to calculate each equipment weight and store it on a table." mean? You haven't asked for any help. You've just told us what you're doing. What calculation do you need to do? What have you attempted? Is the issue how to query? Or is it how to calculate? Or how to split out the pallets? Please make this as easy as possible for us to answer.

Comment: tbl_equipments is not a normalized structure. Is Pallets field a multi-value field or a simple text field with a CSV string? At first glance, 0-001 would be 100, 0-002 would be 50, 0-003 would be 110. Why store an aggregate value that can be calculated when needed? That will require VBA.

Comment: Actually, it can be done without VBA by using an INSERT SELECT if creating new records or using DSum() if updating existing records.

Comment: ``tbl_equipments`` is a multi-value field. Do you have a better structure in mind? Please tell me about it.

Comment: Storing is not necessary as long as I can get the result.

Comment: Do you understand that a multi-value field really just stores links to records in a deep hidden table? Replicating this would mean building a normal dependent table and then probably using form/subform arrangement for data entry.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Pallets field in tbl_equipments is a multi-value field, consider this query:

```
SELECT EquipmentID, Sum(tbl_weights.Weight) AS SumWeight
FROM (tbl_weights INNER JOIN tbl_pallets ON tbl_weights.BillNumber = tbl_pallets.WeightBillNumber) 
INNER JOIN tbl_equipment ON tbl_pallets.PalletID = tbl_equipment.Pallets.Value
GROUP BY tbl_equipment.EquipmentID;
```

Result:

```
EquipmentID SumWeight
O-001         100
O-002          50
O-003         110
```

Note I have not used spaces in naming convention.

Saving calculated aggregate data to table is usually a bad idea. If it can be calculated for saving then it can be calculated when needed.